# What would be a safe/good surfactant for ultrasonic cleaning vinyl records + distilled water and isopropyl alcohol

Tags: home-experiment, polymers, solvents, cleaning, surfactants

Title pretty much says it all besides the type of records I believe are pvc (60s - current, someone correct me if there may be other materials but I absolutely don't have any shellac records) and I plan to use around 50:1 water/ISO. I'm not sure what to use as a surfactant or if it would be of any benefit, though I assume it would. Looking for something 100% safe for records though, and I do have several chemical supply companies around. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd definitely want distilled water. // My other thought was wondering about the paper labels in the center of the record. I suppose that you could suspend the records vertically and spin them slowly - maybe blow liquid off to keep it from flowing down over the label. // Depending on what type of crud is on the records you might need multiple liquid baths. For instance the gunk from cigarette smoke might need some sort  of detergent to remove it effectively.

Comment: @MaxW Spray the cleaner evenly onto the record (not on the label !) while its spinning on the turntable and wipe from the centre out in a slow stroke. I use an already mixed record cleaner I'm not sure what its made of but it's blue liquid.

Comment: @Joel - The OP (Tim) wanted to use an ultrasonic bath. While i do think that would clean the records, I fear that it would destroy the labels. You'd also have to worry about the fibers from the labels getting into the bath and onto the record. I think the OP's approach was overkill and creating other problems. // Your approach seems very sensible.

Comment: @MaxW overkill I agree. I recommend my method to the OP I've been doing it for years same with crew I know. I've never heard of an ultrasonic bath? I spose it depends how dirty the records are. Be careful you don't wear away the grooves in the records with too extensive cleaning or too harsher solvent (:

Comment: Yes brushes are the standard method, however ultrasonic has been proven to be far better and I can confirm that I have had great success so far with some records i had thought were just going to sound bad no matter how much I cleaned. The problem with standard cleaning methods is that they tend to spread/move contaminates around as much as removing them. The labels will just not be immersed and will eventually have a gasket/protector, for now it's immersed by hand up to the label and rotate 1/8 turn per 30 sec. Believe me the ones I've cleaned sound 1000% better, and a surfactant should help.

Comment: Sorry for getting into a tangent on this, but yes there are ultrasonic record cleaning machines on the market for $3-5000.00. And people who own them love them - one pro reviewer even bought his review unit. They don't appear to be much more than a customized us cleaner with motor, brushes, and fans added so there's a lot of people using standard us cleaners and adding a motor etc. Would be great to have for more like 200.00$. Main thing for surfactant is it should dry residue free and be safe for pvc, but I don't know what to use for that.

Comment: Sorry if the above text is messed up - posted on iPhone and it looks like most of the spaces are missing. The messed up part isn't that important anyway.